# Why do authors make a point of $C^1$ functions being continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I've just got a little question on why authors specify things the way they do.  Is their some subtlety I'm missing or are they just being pedantic?

I've encountered the function spaces $C^k[a,b]$ a few times this year and usually the author will make a point that the functions are continuous and have continuous first derivatives, continuous second derivatives, and so on up to $k$.  Why bother specifying it like this?  A differentiable function is necessarily continuous so couldn't we just state $C^k[a,b]$ as the space of real/ complex -valued functions with continuous $k$th derivatives?  Then the functions themselves and their less-than-$k$th derivatives would have to be continuous as well.

Comment: Can you give instances of such "making a point"?

Comment: I would imagine this is exposition an author has learned, from teaching experience, to be useful. You (mostly) don't find this said in research papers, however. On the other hand, I have often seen statements in physics books listing as seemingly separate conditions (that each need to be verified) that some potential function (or something else) is both continuous and its derivative has such and such property.

Comment: @Clement C. I've seen instances of what user337592 is talking about, but I'd have to go home to where my books are and look though them a bit to find some specific examples. (Something I don't plan on doing unless someone, for some reason, is REALLY is interested in examples.)

Comment: Your question is not useful or answerable without specific references.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I have seen instances of the sort, but typically in my experience they arise during a proof involving $f$, when invoking some theorem X: "since $f$ is $C^2$, then in particular $f^\prime$ is continuous and we can apply X to it [...]." In this case, I see no issue -- it is only to clarify why the use of some result is valid. I have never encountered, however, places where the author spells out all the implications of being $C^k$ *to begin with*, without apparent reason.

Comment: @Clement C. I'll look through some of my books, but I won't be able to do this and mention the results until about 24 hours from now.

Comment: @Clement C: Some examples I found this morning: Bishop/Goldberg's **Tensor Analysis on Manifolds** (1980 Dover edition, middle of p. 20): *More generally* $\varphi$ *is* $C^k,$ $k$ *a nonnegative integer, if all partial derivatives up to and including to those of order* $k$ *exist and are continuous.* Spivak's **A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry** Volume 1 (1979 2nd edition, top of p. 45): *A function* $f:{\mathbb R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ *is* $C^r$ *if it has continuous partial derivatives up to order* $r.$ **(continued)**

Comment: **(continuation)**  Millman/Parker's **Elements of Differential Geometry** (1977, p. 11): $f: \mathbf R \rightarrow \mathbf R$ *is of* class $C^k$ *if all derivatives up through order* $k$ *exist and are continuous.*

Comment: Fair enough... well, I am not sure I see why, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. If a function has a k-th derivative it must have a 1st, 2nd,...,(k-1)-th derivative and these have to be continuous. So it is not necessary to mention this. [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/C-kFunction.html) starts its article about $C^k$ functions with

> A function with k continuous derivatives is called a $C^k$ function.  ...

Of course one also could say

> A function with a continuous k-th derivative is called $C^k$ function. ...

Answer (score 2):

As Dave Renfro commented, this may be useful for pedagogical reasons, even if it's logically unnecessary.  One difficulty that people often have is putting too much trust in formulas.  Of course if $f'$ is to exist, $f$ must be continuous, but a **formula** for $f'$ might sometimes exist and be continuous without $f$ being continuous.  If you don't first check for discontinuities of $f$, you might miss them.  As a simple example, consider 
$$ f(x) = \arctan(\tan(x))$$
The naive student, asked to check if $f$ is $C^1$, might start by computing
with the Chain Rule $$ f'(x) = 1 $$
see no sign of discontinuity there, and conclude that $f$ is $C^1$.

Of course, it's easy for a somewhat less naive student to see the error in this case, but more complicated examples can arise that can even catch experts off guard.  For example, a "closed-form" antiderivative of a meromorphic function
will typically have branch cuts, even though the poles are not real; whether the branch cuts intersect the real axis, and if so where, is often not obvious.  This often arises with antiderivatives produced by Computer Algebra systems.